# Instagram MediaID/Shortcode to URL

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm making a sequence of API calls to Instagram Graph API in order to publish an image.
As described in their [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/) I'm making two calls as follows:

POST https://graph.facebook.com/API_VERSION/IG_USER_ID/media

with params:

```
{
   access_token: IG_USER_ACCESSTOKEN,
   image_url: "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-square-4/1024/instagram-512.png",
   caption: "Caption goes here",
}
```

returns:

```
{ id: 17859694922405416 }
```

Then I get the media container id from this call and I make another one to publish it:

POST https://graph.facebook.com/API_VERSION/IG_USER_ID/media_publish

with parameters:

```
{
   creation_id: CONTAINER_ID_TAKEN_FROM_THE_PREVIOUS_CALL,
   access_token: IG_USER_ACCESSTOKEN
}
```

This returns another ID which then I convert into a shortcode (using a function I found handy).

```
{
   id: '17872941842175967',
   id_str: '17872941842175967',
}
```

Result shortcode is : `_f1iNmBff`

I cannot seem to find the proper URL to see that image in the browser.
I've tried with: https://www.instagram.com/p/_f1iNmBff/, but it says that the page cannot be found.

I've even tried to check on the media container status with another call and it says that the status is **FINISHED** (but not **PUBLISHED**).

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Could anyone answer me, please?

Comment: Looks like you can get a permalink from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/media/.